# Bokeh - how to create a hideable sidebar

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have a bokeh project that looks very similar to this https://demo.bokeh.org/movies
Now I would like to make it possible to hide/unhide the column on the left.

I know how to hide it following the solution from here https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/hiding-bokeh-elements/4335/2

The problem is now where to put a button which would show the column again.
I thought of the following:

- When hiding the column make another button visible which will allow to unhide the column. This is easy but adding a new widget to the layout would defeat the purpose of hiding the column since either way I would have a big button visible on the screen affecting the position of the figure. Is there some way of adding a new button widget which does not affect the whole layout?
- Adding a new tool to the figure which would call the unhide the column. I am not sure though if this can be done easily.

Comment: Just put another button to toggle sidebar. It's the best practice for UX.

Comment: That's what I meant with the first option. But how can I put it somewhere without making figure adapt to its position?

Comment: A button of any kind is an element that must be visible in order to be useful. Even if it's visible only when you hover over something, that something still has to be visible. So, there has to be some visible element there, and the layout simply doesn't have a choice but to take it into account. Where you place it is up to you, but usually it's placed right near the panel that it toggles. It's OK if the button takes space and moves the figure a bit.